# Prove an edge that minimizes the Euclidean distance crossing a cut is in the Delaunay triangulation

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two disjoint point sets in the plane. (Think of them as a red point set and a black point set.) Let $p \in P$ and $q \in Q$ be two points from these sets that minimize the
Euclidean distance $|pq|$. Prove that $pq$ is an edge of $\text{DT}(P\cup Q)$.

---

I know this property of DT,
the closest neighbor b to any point p is on an edge bp in the Delaunay triangulation since the nearest neighbor graph is a subgraph of the Delaunay triangulation.

Is this sufficient to prove the proposition above?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others.  Some may consider it impolite to delete your question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since $pq$ may not be in the nearest neighbor graph.

[image: p'(-3,1), p(-2,0), q(2,0), q'(3,1) made by https://www.overleaf.com/project/621a9034c0cff3abea32d201 and https://pixlr.com/e/#editor]

For example, let $P=\{(-3,1), (-2, -0)\}$ and $Q=\{(2,0), (3, 1)\}$. Then $p=(-2,0)$ and $q=(2,0)$. However, the nearest neighbor graph, which consists of edge $pp'$ and edge $qq'$, does not contain edge $pq$.

---

Here is a useful property of Delaunay triangulation.

If a circle passing through two given points doesn't contain any other given points in its interior, the line segment between the two points is an edge of a Delaunay triangulation of the given points. If, furthermore, there is no given points on the boundary of the circle, that line segment is an edge of every Delaunay triangulation.